# Can DHCP Option121 work with DHCP Option3 together?

Tags: linux, dhcp

I have a router with DHCP Option3(Router) set, and it works well.

[image: DHCP Option3]

My Ubuntu22.04 machine was able to configure the default route automatically.

[image: Ubuntu Route Option3 Only]

Yesterday, I configured DHCP Option121 (Classless route) on my DHCP Server.

[image: DHCP Option121]

After this configuration change, my Windows machine was able to get both configuration information (3 and 121) from DHCP.

However, my Ubuntu22.04 machines dropped configuration information from Option3 and no default route is configured.

[image: Ubuntu Route Option121 Configured]

I wonder if this is by design? Or did I misconfigure anything?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"If the DHCP server returns both a Classless Static Routes option and a Router option, the DHCP client MUST ignore the Router option."

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3442.html